# ffmpeg code does not link (undefined reference to avcodec_register_all

Tags: c, linker, ffmpeg, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile a simple introductory program using `ffmpeg` that tries to check if the `mp3` codec is available. While the code compiles OK, I am facing difficulty in solving linker errors. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

float *generateSinusoid(unsigned int sampleRate, unsigned int nSecondsAudio) {

  unsigned int nsamples = (nSecondsAudio * sampleRate);
  float *arr;
  arr = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * nsamples);
  int i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < nsamples; i++) {
    arr[i] = 20 * sin(2.f * (M_PI) * (330/sampleRate) * i);  /*frequency of 330H
z*/
  }

  return arr;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  avcodec_register_all();

  AVCodec *codec;

  unsigned int sampleRate = 22050;  /*assumed.*/
  unsigned int nSecondsAudio = 4;
  float *arr;
  arr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * nSecondsAudio * sampleRate);

  /*Step 1. Generate sinusoid.*/
  arr = generateSinusoid(sampleRate, nSecondsAudio);

  /* Step 2. See if encoder exists.*/
  /*codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);*/

  if(!codec) {  /*codec = NULL.*/
    printf("MP3 codec not found!!!!");
  } else {
    printf("MP3 codec found!!!");
  }

   return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled and linked like so:

```
encoding_mp3: encoding_mp3.o
        gcc encoding_mp3.o -o encoding_mp3 -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/lib/w32api -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_dev/lib -lm -luser32 -lpthread -lavcodec

encoding_mp3.o: encoding_mp3.c
        gcc -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_dev/include -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/usr/include -g -c encoding_mp3.c -o encoding_mp3.o

clean:
        rm encoding_mp3.o encoding_mp3
```

Linking gives the following error:

```
gcc -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_dev/include -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/usr/include -g -c encoding_mp3.c -o encoding_mp3.o
gcc encoding_mp3.o -o encoding_mp3 -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/lib/w32api -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_dev/lib -lm -luser32 -lpthread -lavcodec
encoding_mp3.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Desktop/webserver/cygnus/ffmpeg/work/encoding_mp3.c:31: undefined reference to `_avcodec_register_all'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [encoding_mp3] Error 1
```

I have gone through most of the threads on SO regarding this problem and here is what I have tried so far:
- Put libraries at the end of all non-option arguments
- Commented out code that references functions. This seems to work. The `undefined reference` errors go away after all function calls are removed, though the presence of a struct `AVCodec` does not cause any problems.

Any help on this is most welcome.

Comment: i think you also need to link libavformat, libavutil also.

Comment: It seems like that there are some problems in your libavcodec, since it compiles fine here. Would you please try "nm -D (your libavcodec lib)" and find if there is "avcodec_register_all" in it?

Comment: @HenryHu: I tried `nm -D libavcodec.dll.a` (which is the libavcodec) and it spat out an error message: `File format not recognized`.

Comment: Try to add `extern "C" { }` around the `#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>`

Comment: @pogorskiy: I will try your suggestion. But `encoding_mp3.c` is C code. No C++.

Comment: @pogorskiy: Yep. `gcc` throws a parsing error on `extern "C"` which is as it should be given that this is C code.

Comment: You can not write `avcodec_register_all` function call before variable declarations in C.

Comment: Is there a libavcodec.a in the directory you anticipate?  Did you figure this out?:)